# Scrollbar issues x2

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, css

I have a small content box that is scrollable, the side scrollbar is custom via java script for iframes, I can get rid of it using:

overflow-y: scroll;
overflow-x: hidden;

BUT it stops my java code from working....

```css
body{ 
background-color: #372d24;
width: 100%;
height: 1000px;
}

#header{
width: 100%;
height:24px;
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
background-image: url(http://i65.tinypic.com/29lxow1.jpg);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

#header2{
width: 100%;
height: 205px;
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
top: 24px;
background-color: #d7d1cb;
}

#logo{
width: 500px;
height: 205px;
background-image: url(http://i65.tinypic.com/nbt3y9.png);
position: absolute;
left: 500px;
top: 20px;
}

#navione{
position: absolute;
left: 75px;
top: 45px;

}

#navitwo{
position: absolute;
left: 280px;
top: 45px;

}

#navigation {
  width: 200px;  
  line-height: 7px;
}


#navigation a:link, #navigation a:visited, #navigation a:active {
  display: block;
  font: 8px  "small fonts", "century gothic";
  text-transform: lowercase; 
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 2px; 
  background-color: #d7d1cb;
  border-color: #392f3f;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  color: #392f3f; 
  padding: 7px 3px;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all .5s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all .5s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all .5s ease-out;
  transition: all .5s ease-out;
}

#navigation a:hover {
  background-color: #392f3f;
  color: #ffd6d0;
  padding: 7px 9px;
}

#updates{
width: 560px;
height: 196px;
position: absolute;
left: 1006px;
top: 26px;

}

iframe {
width: 560px;
height: 196px;


}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://babywitch.altervista.org/Characters/stylesheet.css">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header"> </div>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
<div id="header2"></div>
<div id="logo"></div>


<div id="navione">
<div id="navigation">
    <a href="http://google.com">H o m e</a><br>
    <a href="http://yahoo.com">A b o u t</a><br>
    <a href="http://yahoo.com">N A V I</a><br>
    <a href="http://bing.com">F A Q</a><br>
      <a href="http://bing.com">M E D I A</a><br>
</div></div>


<div id="navitwo">
<div id="navigation">
    <a href="http://google.com">link 5</a><br>
    <a href="http://yahoo.com">link 2</a><br>
    <a href="http://yahoo.com">link 3</a><br>
    <a href="http://bing.com">link 4</a><br>
      <a href="http://bing.com">link 5</a><br>
</div></div>

<div id="updates">

<div style="background:#fff;">

 <iframe name="updates" src="http://babywitch.altervista.org/Characters/updates.html" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="no" scrolling="yes" style="border-width:0px; border-color:#; background:#d7d1cb; border-style:solid; height: 200px;">
 </iframe>

</div>







</div>




</body>
</html>
```

The three java script codes are here:

[here](http://babywitch.altervista.org/Characters/jquery.slimscroll.min.js) and [here](http://babywitch.altervista.org/Characters/scroll.js)

Comment: you want to hidden overflow-x for window ??

Comment: I think so? I want the white bar in the screenshot to dissapear.. I could only think of doing that which makes it go away but it prevents the custom scrollbar I want to not work anymore..

Comment: The height of the body 1000px is coz of the x scroll bar..

Answer (score 0):

If you want yo hide the x-scroll bar of the browser just make it simple. change the body css only..

```
body{ 
background: #372d24;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

But if you want to clear both scroll bar x and y you need change lots of css. In your css you set some background-image, background-color. I change them to background only and set background-repeat: no-repeat; But  I don't change the css header repeat-x. If you have any question regarding this ask me in comment. But you can make this page simply with bootstrap. Anyways here is the answer 
And if possible change id contant width:100%  to min-width:95% And ignore  console log error in snippet

```js
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script> 

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery-slimScroll/1.3.8/jquery.slimscroll.min.js">
</script>


$(function(){
$('#content').slimScroll({
width: '100%',
height: '100%',
color: '#FF0000',
allowPageScroll: false, 
});
});
```

```css
body
{ 
 background: #372d24;
 min-width: 100%;
 background-repeat:no-repeat !important;
 }

#header{
min-width: 100vw;
height:24px;
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
background: url(http://i65.tinypic.com/29lxow1.jpg);
background-repeat:repeat-x;
}

#header2{
width: 100%;
height: 205px;
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
top: 24px;
background: #d7d1cb;
background-repeat:no-repeat; 
}

#logo{
width: 500px;
height: 205px;
background: url(http://i65.tinypic.com/nbt3y9.png);
position: absolute;
left: 500px;
top: 20px;
background-repeat:no-repeat; 
}

#navione{
position: absolute;
left: 75px;
top: 45px;

}

#navitwo{
position: absolute;
left: 280px;
top: 45px;

}

#navigation {
  width: 200px;  
  line-height: 7px;
}


#navigation a:link, #navigation a:visited, #navigation a:active {
  display: block;
  font: 8px  "small fonts", "century gothic";
  text-transform: lowercase; 
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 2px; 
  background: #d7d1cb;
  background-repeat:no-repeat; 
  border-color: #392f3f;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  color: #392f3f; 
  padding: 7px 3px;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all .5s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all .5s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all .5s ease-out;
  transition: all .5s ease-out;
}

#navigation a:hover {
  background: #392f3f;
  background-repeat:no-repeat; 
  color: #ffd6d0;
  padding: 7px 9px;
}

#updates{
 position: absolute;
 left: 1006px;
 top: 26px;
 right: 0;
}

iframe {
min-width: 100%;
height: 196px;
}

#contant{
width:95% !important;
}
```

```html
   
<body>
 <div id="header">
 </div>
  
<div id="header2">
</div>
<div id="logo">
</div>


  

   <div id="navione">
      <div id="navigation">
       <a href="http://google.com">H o m e</a><br>
        <a href="http://yahoo.com">A b o u t</a><br>
        <a href="http://yahoo.com">N A V I</a><br>
        <a href="http://bing.com">F A Q</a><br>
        <a href="http://bing.com">M E D I A</a><br>
      </div>
    </div>

 

<div id="navitwo">
 <div id="navigation">
    <a href="http://google.com">link 5</a><br>
    <a href="http://yahoo.com">link 2</a><br>
    <a href="http://yahoo.com">link 3</a><br>
    <a href="http://bing.com">link 4</a><br>
    <a href="http://bing.com">link 5</a><br>
  </div>
 </div>


 <div id="updates"> 

 <iframe name="updates" 
    src="http://babywitch.altervista.org/Characters/updates.html"
    marginwidth="0"  marginheight="0" frameborder="no">
  

 </iframe>

   
 </div>

 </body>

 </html>
```